# How to validate laravel input only when data is present?

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-8

So I have a Laravel form where I'm collecting data, I use same form for creating and updating the table. Problem is that I only want the input fields to be validated when they contain data, this is my validation logic.

```php
$validated = $request->validate([
            'site_name' => 'sometimes|string',
            'site_email' => 'sometimes|email',
            'site_keywords' => 'sometimes|string',
            'site_description' => 'sometimes|string',
            'site_acronym' => 'sometimes|string|max:7',
            'site_favicon' => 'sometimes|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,svg',
            'site_logo' => 'sometimes||mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,svg',
            'site_currency' => 'sometimes|string',
            'site_currency_symbol' => 'sometimes|string',
        ]);
```

But when the form is submitted, laravel returns an error for empty input fields, e.g it returns an error like so ***"The site name must be a string."*** for the first validation rule.

What am I doing wrong please?

**EDIT**

So I took the advice from @roj-vroemen and modified my code by using the nullable validation rule and it works just fine now.
Here's the new code block

```
$validated = $request->validate([
            'site_name' => 'string|nullable|sometimes',
            'site_email' => 'email|nullable|sometimes',
            'site_keywords' => 'string|nullable|sometimes',
            'site_description' => 'string|nullable|sometimes',
            'site_acronym' => 'string|nullable|sometimes|max:7',
            'site_favicon' => 'mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,svg|nullable|sometimes',
            'site_logo' => 'mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,svg|nullable|sometimes',
            'site_currency' => 'string|nullable|sometimes',
            'site_currency_symbol' => 'string|nullable|sometimes',
        ]);
```

Comment: Are you using javascript to submit the form?

Comment: No, no javascript, it's plain blade.

Comment: have you tried nullable?

Comment: Are you just wanting the validation to pass if a field is `null` or are you also wanting to remove it from the `validated` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use `nullable` in this case. `sometimes` basically means it only runs the validation for that field when it's present in the data.

In short:
Use `nullable` when you want to allow `null` values.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-nullable

Use `sometimes` if your only want to validate the field when it's present in the given input array.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#validating-when-present

Note: you might want to make sure to filter out the empty values as the fields containing `null` will still be there:
`$validated = array_filter($validated);`

Comment: I combined nullable and sometimes and now it works as I want. Thanks for your help

Comment: I also observed that order matters in writing the validation rules, when I placed sometimes at the end it worked better compared to when I had it coming first. Is my observation correct?

Comment: I'm not sure actually, don't see a note about it in the documentation and didn't see anything that suggests it when scanning the source code but I could've missed it of course :)